# A-Frame in webflow is taking up entire screen

Tags: aframe, webflow

I'm trying to use A-Frame within Webflow, however, I've hit a roadblock pretty quick. 
The embedded A-Frame element will always take up 100% of the screen with no ability to scroll or anything, as if in full screen constantly.

I just want the A-Frame element to fit within a box (A div specifically) on the page allowing me to display other content on the page around it as well. I tried looking through their content and guides as well as searching to no avail.

Currently, I have my:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

Within the project settings > custom code > Head section

and then the actual A-Frame content code within a specifically sized div element using the embed tool:

```
 <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
      <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
      <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
      <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [embedded component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/embedded.html#sidebar) or use an `<iframe>` to place your scene.